# Upgrade only first n number of packages in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I want to upgrade only first 10 packages in upgrade list in debian because it's total size is too large to download at single time. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Please explain more about your motivation. Is it about monthly data limits?

Comment: yes its daily data limit. :-(

Comment: My first comment was slightly wrong. I verified the correct syntax; see my answer below.

Comment: By the way, welcome to [su]!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) as shown below.
[image]
Ubuntu Debian Linux offers the Synaptic Package Manager for direct install through their "store", or see [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager) for manual installation.

Comment: I highly recommend Synaptic in general, but it might be a pain to download on a limit.

Comment: Your answer is nice . But just for curiosity .. How to upgrade using terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upgrade only certain packages from the command-line with

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name> <another-package> ...
```

You could then upgrade each package individually, if need be. Before downloading, it will confirm the download and install size (unless it's trivially small).

Also, you can watch the download carefully, and then interrupt it (with Ctl+C) when it gets too close to your limit. Any partially downloaded packages will be retried from the same point next time.

---

By the way, when installing new packages on a limit, you can use apt-get install --download-only , which allows you to download a package without installing it. This is useful when you need to download a program with many dependencies, which together would go over your limit. By installing one or several of the dependencies separately, you can avoid going over limit, without having to babysit the download.

Once you've downloaded all the needed packages, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install --no-download <package>
```

Comment: That means i have to manually **copy and paste each package** name. :'-( . Dude its 725 packages to upgrade .....

Comment: Not according to your post:: " I want to upgrade only first 10 packages in upgrade list". Which statement is correct?